# API not Returning any SQL data Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, api, postman

I'm trying to join two tables together then use an API to retrieve the data in JSON format.

When i join the tables in PHPMyAdmin, it works fine however when i use the exact same SQL statement in my PHP code and use Postman to test it, nothing is returned.

Please help,

Many thanks,

```
PHP CODE:

$app->get('/api/getbooking', function(Request $request, Response $response){
     session_id('TEST'); // NEED TO FIND A WAY TO CARRY SESSIONS OVER SUBDOMAINS - ASSIGNING THE ID IS BAD!
     session_start();
    //$sql = "Select * from login where username ='{$_SESSION['Username']}'";


     $sql= "SELECT *
      FROM booking 
      INNER JOIN artistlocation ON booking.ArtistID = artistlocation.ArtistID
      WHERE CustomerID = 13";

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $customers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($customers);

        //This whole block of code needs improving
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you set `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` in your db class to make PDO throw exceptions if the queries fail?

Comment: Also, when you say "nothing is returned", do you get an empty array or absolutely nothing? (white page of death)? Do you have error reporting/display errors turned on? Checked the error log?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hi Magnus, I have set that attribute. And absolutely nothing is returned. In the Postman results box, there isn't anything. No empty arrays, nothing :(

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I might know, hang on

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the help Magnus, i fixed it. Basically i had a BLOB/img i was retrieving and i was trying to convert that into JSON and it obviously didn't like it :)